# Is there a Linux tool to extract multiple cropped pieces from a single image?

Tags: image, imagemagick, crop, gimp

I've seen questions about extracting a similarly-located cropped area from multiple images. This problem is the exact opposite and I haven't found any helpful tools.

I have images with multiple areas to be extracted into separate picture files.  The location of the extraction areas varies from picture to picture, in shape and size, and number of areas, but are generally rectangular.  I've tried ImageMagick and other tools but none provide an interactive mode with this kind of capability and all are painful at best.

For example, imagine a picture of a bookshelf.  Most books are upright, the book thicknesses vary as does the height of the books, and a few are angled and hold up the others. What I'm looking for is a tool to extract the spine of each book to a separate image (with a name pattern ("spines-%%" for example), or a suffix of the original would be fine, e.g., "books.png would give "books-1.png", "books-2.png" etc.  The original "books.png" would be kept.  The ability to rename each cropped piece would be good.)  The idea is to draw the first crop box, press an "extract" button when it's the right size/shape, then do another crop box, and another, any number of times.

With ImageMagick, GIMP, etc., one must currently:
- examine each image, and determine the number of desired extractions in advance
- make a copy of the original image for each desired extraction, changing the name slightly for each
- edit (with magick, gimp, etc): place a crop box, crop to that, save each cropped image (ImageMagick and others) or export it (GIMP), overwriting the full (e.g. bookshelf image copy) image with the now much smaller cropped box portion
- close that file and open the next of the set (or use Next in ImageMagick - a minor but helpful thing)
- delete the original multi-image files if desired, or move them to safety

Then, do this for hundreds of composite images. Ouch! Scripts like multicrop and multicrop2 can't do this because they require well defined gaps between the book spines.  CLI tools can't do it because the location of the spines and their sizes change in every picture.  As noted, GIMP, ImageMagick, gthumb, etc can do it one-by-one but it is a huge amount of work with a lot of intermediate steps and files, and the potential for even a small error (like miscounting the number of books on a shelf) by just one number requires a do-over. Attempting to automate based on book color, text, etc. would be a massive undertaking itself, and what if the next image to multi-crop is different, say extracting a cropped view of each billiard ball from a billiard table?  The book-based pre-processor wouldn't work (although multicrop2 might, if the balls were far enough apart that the green felt could be used as a separator).

Thoughts, anybody?

Comment: This community is amazing.  I gotten two great answers and several helpful comments.  I've been trying the ImageMagick script below and am getting good results on typical bookshelves; the best about this solution is that the description of what is being done and why is excellent - read it even if you don't have to process images like this (I haven't tried it but it may work for a variety of other types of pictures too).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using ImageMagick. ImageMagick is installed on Linux and is available for Windows and Mac OSX.  This is just a demonstration. It only works on a single shelf at a time.

The idea is to trim the image to remove most of the white borders. Then get the Canny edges and filter out the shorter ones using connected components. Then get the Hough lines and filter to those that delineate the vertical sides of the books. Draw the hough lines as black on white background. Then use connected components again to identify the bounding boxes of the larger white regions that should correspond to the books and discards the smaller ones. Finally, loop over the bounding boxes to crop the image into each book.

Input:

[image]

This section of the code trims the image to remove excess white. Then extracts the Canny edges. Then filters the edges to remove small ones using connected components. Then it computes the Hough lines and filters those using AWK to get the line endpoints for those lines that are perfectly vertical or 1 degree off vertical. The endpoints are stored in an array.

```
lineArr=(`convert bookshelf.jpg \
-trim +repage +write bookshelf_trim.png \
-canny 0x1+20%+50% +write bookshelf_edges.png \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=300 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 +write bookshelf_edges_filtered.png \
-stroke black -strokewidth 2 \
-hough-lines 9x9+70 +write bookshelf_lines.png MVG:- | \
awk '{ if( $6 == 0 || $6 == 1) {print $2","$3}}'`)

num=${#lineArr[*]}
echo $num
echo "${lineArr[*]}"
```

This part of the code sets up the trimmed image and white image onto which to draw the lines.

```
convert bookshelf_trim.png bookshelf_lines_filtered.png
convert bookshelf_trim.png -fill white -colorize 100 bookshelf_lines_filtered2.png
```

This part of the code loops over each line and draws it on the above two images.

```
for((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
line="${lineArr[$i]}"
x1=`echo $line | cut -d, -f1`
y1=`echo $line | cut -d, -f2`
x2=`echo $line | cut -d, -f3`
y2=`echo $line | cut -d, -f4`
echo "$x1,$y1 $x2,$y2"
convert bookshelf_lines_filtered.png -fill black -stroke black -strokewidth 2 -draw "line $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2" -alpha off bookshelf_lines_filtered.png
convert bookshelf_lines_filtered2.png -fill black -stroke black -strokewidth 2 -draw "line $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2" -alpha off bookshelf_lines_filtered2.png
done
```

This part of the code uses connected components on the white image with the black lines draw to extract the bounding boxes of the white sections.

```
bboxArr=(`convert bookshelf_lines_filtered2.png \
-type bilevel \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=0 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 \
+write bookshelf_regions.png null: | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`)

num=${#bboxArr[*]}
echo "${bboxArr[*]}"
```

This final part of the code loops over each bounding box and crops the trimmed input image to get each book.

```
for((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox="${bboxArr[$i]}"
convert bookshelf_trim.png -crop $bbox +repage bookshelf_$i.jpg
done
```

Canny edges:

[image]

Filtered edges:

[image]

Hough lines:

[image]

Filtered lines on input:

[image]

Filtered lines on white background:

[image]

A few of the 19 cropped books:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: WOW!  That's one very impressive result, and the instructions with how you assembled it are invaluable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[nip2](https://github.com/libvips/nip2), the [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) GUI, lets you drag a crop box and save at each position with a single click. It's part of most linuxes, just check your package manager. It comes with a manual: press F1 for help.

Load the image, double-click to open a view window, hold down CTRL and drag down and right to create a region and position it ovber one of the objects. Back in the main window, right-click on the region and pick "Save As". In the file dialog, tick "Increment filename", enter a name like "area0001.png", then press "OK" in the file save dialog.

[image]

The save dialog will stay pinned up and the filename will increment. Now reposition the region over another object and press OK again. You can keep doing this -- it'll be just one click for each save.

You can do rotated rectangular selections too: just select Toolkits /  Image / Transform / Rotate / Free to make a rotated image, then mark the region on that. You'll be able to drag the rotate slider each time to get the object upright.

Comment: This is a usable solution, and I'll read the manual (the instructions above to don't appear to be working in the same order).  It's easy to use and (fortunately?) I have only about 200 files that need extraction (which will result in about 3000 eventual saved regions).  So while a bit "wordy" for that many, it beats the alternatives I've found so far.

Comment: Should have said: "Thank you for the tip about nip2!"

Comment: Huh the instructions should work. Please follow up with a note about what worked for you, and  I'll update the answer. Glad it's useful!

Comment: I was creating new regions - filename increment didn't work across those (despite multiple attempts ;-!).  I went to the git sites, went through documents and didn't see how it could work using *multiple* regions, as I was doing.  Then I recalled your comment.  You said "reposition" and that DOES work, and quite well.  So the secret is to create a region (CTRL-mouse), which will get a name like "A2".  Don't create another!  Instead, move the mouse over the corners and resize / reposition the box, then press Save again, then use the mouse to move the corners of A2 again, press save again, etc.

Comment: I've tried to make it clearer, thanks! Also, drag on the label to move the region without resizing, in case it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

[`ofn-extract-objects`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) is a script that extracts and exports in one shot and in as many files as necessary all non-contiguous opaque areas on a layer. So if you can erase the parts you don't need and isolate each book spine it can do the rest.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work but appear to be running into a common GIMP problem - python version.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @JD53 From your answer above, it seems you didn't use the plugin correctly... It isn't main to be called form the command line, but accessed in Gimp menus after loading the image in the editor.

Comment: OS is Linux 20.04.  To the second post, I was attempting to run from inside GIMP (v 2.10) but GIMP will not load the plugin due to Python version / libraries.  System default Python is 2.7.18. During GIMP startup it spits error messages that the plug in cannot import the module.  Attempting to install that module (with pip) shows no such library; searches for an installable paclage with it (even at the ofn code site) didn't help.  Using pyenv I switched to Python 3.7.6, tried the same plug-in, which failed to include the module *and* exhibited the "print" statement ( ) problem.

Comment: Oh, and hunting down that problem led to numerous websites describing GIMP use of older Python versions, and version sensitivity problems.